# how to measure the battery usage for android process running in shell

Tags: android, battery

I need to calculate the power consumption of running an artificial intelligence model on a mobile phone. I can currently only do this by running run.sh in the shell or put it into an application. I'm not sure if the power consumption counted by the system after put it into an application is the same as running it in the shell. If it's not the same, how should I calculate the power consumption of the process running in the shell?